# Starting an event after closing JFrame window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

After i close my window,i want to create an object of a class and preform a task.
After closing:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

What can i do so that it can start a new operation as soon as window is closed?
please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
After i close my window,i want to create an object of a class and preform a task.
```

look at

- `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` simplair as `setVisible(false);`, container is re_usable, is possible to show it by calling `setVisible(true);`
- or you can to call `dispose()`, meaning that this container isn't re_usable, have to check `isDisplayable()`, before calling `setVisible(true);`

> i want to create an object of a class and preform a task

- see [SystemTray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html), maybe could be proper way

Answer (score 2):

When the user tries to close a `JFrame`, the following events happen :

- the `windowClosing` method of the `WindowListener`s registered on that frame are invoked.
- then, the action specified by `setDefaultCloseOperation` is triggered.

There are 4 default close operations :

#### do nohting on close

...does nothing at all. The frame is still here, happily ignoring your requests to close it.

#### hide on close

Same effect as calling `setVisible(false)` on the frame. The frame becomes invisible, and it can be displayed again by calling `setVisible(true)`.

#### dispose on close

Same effect as calling `dispose()` on the frame. The effect is somewhat similar to HIDE_ON_CLOSE, the difference is that this time, the OS resources used by the frame are released. You can still call `setVisible(true)` again if you want to make the frame appear again.

The `windowClosed` method of the `WindowListener`s registered on that frame are invoked.

Also, note that when the last displayable window is disposed of, [your program may terminate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/AWTThreadIssues.html).

#### exit on close

Same effect as calling `System.exit()`.

---

So, if you want to have full control on what happens when the user tries to close a frame, set the default operation to DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE, and put your code in the `windowClosing` method of a `WindowListener`. There, you can call setVisible(false), dispose() or System.exit(), depending on what you want to achieve.

You can also set the default operation to hide, dispose, or exit on close, and put your code in the `windowClosing` method of a `WindowListener`. In this case, the listener will be invoked first, and then the chosen action will be executed, no matter what.

Finally, you can also set the default operation to DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE, and put your code in the `windowClosed` method of a `WindowListener`. That way, the frame is first disposed (it disappears from the screen), and then your code gets executed.

Comment: any other way insted of 'WindowListener'

Comment: Swing is an event-driven framework. Adding listeners on relevant events is the only way of being notified of a GUI event.

Answer (score 1):

Call

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

and register a listener for the closing event:

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        JFrame frame = (JFrame)e.getSource();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // additional code here
    }
});
```

Comment: any other way insted of adding a listener?

Comment: I think you need to add System.exit(0) there as well, because the current implementation of joey does that.

Comment: @W.Goeman: this is done by `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

Comment: @joeyrohan why not using a listener? This is the most elegant way. Anyway I don't know another solution.

Comment: @joeyrohan You could post your home work exercise. Maybe you got something wrong.